# How to put ArrayList<File> in bundle?

Tags: java, android, bundle

I have an application to store all the files that are on the user's device. I want to upload them to the app once, and then restore them from the bundle. But I do not know how to put in the bundle ArrayList, since the File class does not implement the Parcelable interface

Comment: why don't you just pass ```ArrayList<String>``` and that list will store file path instead of file object .

Comment: All further work is already done with the File class, and if I create a file using its path every time, does it make sense to save data in a bundle??

Comment: Nobody told you to creata files every time. Not even one time.

Comment: But all the next code is working with File class... Maybe I just don't understand some concepts

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by creating the custom class that extended File class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).